# CDT GDB Debug under Windows

Tags: windows, gdb, mingw, eclipse-cdt

I was trying to use CDT with MinGW under Windows 7. It could run the program without any mistakes; however, when I started debugging, it prompted the following messages. I've no idea where the problem was. Any comments are welcome. Thanks in advance.

> Failed to execute MI command:-gdb-set auto-solib-add on
>   Error message from debugger back end:
>   No symbol "auto" in current context.
>
> Request for monitor: 'RequestMonitor (org.eclipse.cdt.dsf.concurrent.RequestMonitorWithProgress@199abd1): Status ERROR: org.eclipse.cdt.dsf.gdb code=10004 Failed to execute MI command:-gdb-set auto-solib-add on
>   Error message from debugger back end:
>   No symbol "auto" in current context. null' resulted in an error.
>
> Process terminate failed
>
> Error in final launch sequence
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Failed to execute MI command:
>   -gdb-set auto-solib-add on
>   Error message from debugger back end:
>   No symbol "auto" in current context.

```
at org.eclipse.cdt.dsf.concurrent.Sequence.abortExecution(Sequence.java:560)

at org.eclipse.cdt.dsf.concurrent.Sequence.access$4(Sequence.java:552)

at org.eclipse.cdt.dsf.concurrent.Sequence$2.handleErrorOrWarning(Sequence.java:424)

at org.eclipse.cdt.dsf.concurrent.RequestMonitor.handleFailure(RequestMonitor.java:321)

at org.eclipse.cdt.dsf.concurrent.RequestMonitor.handleCompleted(RequestMonitor.java:284)

at org.eclipse.cdt.dsf.concurrent.RequestMonitor$2.run(RequestMonitor.java:246)

at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)

at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)

at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)

at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(Unknown Source)

at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source)

at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)

at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)

at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other version of gdb is solution.